Invariant Violation: "TAPPS" has not been registered. This can happen if:
In my react native project in android  is working fine  but when I run same project in IOS  with Xcode it giving me this error :
ERROR  Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "TAPPS" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I have try multiple option  available on internet but none of them is working .
